# How to create tables out of XML files efficiently with Python?

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, lxml

I'm trying to find the best solution for a problem below. I'm using Python to take an xml file, search for elements I'm interested in and return their associated values. If the elements are missing then I'd want to return a null, none or equivalent value.

At the moment I'm using lxml and xpath syntax but we're finding it quite slow as I'm having to loop through lots of the same element to test in python if a value exists or not.

I'm using xpath to create a custom dictionary, of which I can then flatten into something like Pandas.

Example structure is:

```
Holding 1 - Contains 3 children

<Holding id = 1>
  <Name> x </Name>
  <Date> x </Date>
  <Flavour> x </Flavour>
</Holding>

Holding 2 - Contains only two children 

<Holding id = 2>
  <Name> y </Name>
  <Date> y </Date>
</Holding>
```

I'd need something that if Flavour is missing, returns a default value.

If I just choose to pull all text from each holding I end with values of differing lengths.

List one would have the values for Name, Date, Flavour.
List two would only have the values for Name and Date.

An example is below. I'm looking through each portfolio, each holding and pulling back the text for Rank.

```
Dict['Rank'] = root.xpath(f'//ns:Portfolio[{each_portfolio + 1}]/ns:Holdings/*[{each_holding + 1}]/ns:Rank/text()', namespaces = {'ns' : nsurl}))
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, `lxml` xpath has no such a feature as a default value in case the element is missing. You need to check by yourself in python if the value exists. Which you said you're already doing.

Comment: I suppose you have a list of the elements that you are interested in. Can any element be missing? I don't think there is an XPath "trick" you can use here. But perhaps someone can come up with a suggestion if you provide a [mcve] that we can try for ourselves.